# Calculating Financial dates in Spark SQL

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a requirement to calculate financial year, financial quarter etc from a given date in Spark SQL in the SQL API. Can anyone please help me accomplish this.

Few examples are as follows :

Input Date: `2021-06-24`

Output:

```
fncl_yr_key = 2021
fncl_qtr_key = 202104
fncl_mon = 12
lst_day_mon = 2021-06-30
```

Input Date: `2021-09-16`
Output:

```
fncl_yr_key = 2022
fncl_qtr_key = 202201
fncl_mon = 3
lst_day_mon = 2021-09-30
```

Input Date: `2022-02-10`
Output:

```
fncl_yr_key = 2022
fncl_qtr_key = 202203
fncl_mon = 8
lst_day_mon = 2022-02-28
```

I need to do this in SQL. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Looks like you have posted the [same question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68126971/2129801) twice

Answer (score 0):

Following is sample spark sql query which does what you are looking for:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import last_day, year, month
spark.sql("""SELECT  CASE WHEN (month(creation_date) > 6) THEN (year(creation_date) +1)  ELSE (year(creation_date)) end  AS fncl_yr_key, CASE WHEN (month(creation_date) > 6) THEN (month(creation_date) -6)  ELSE (month(creation_date) + 6) end  AS fncl_mon, last_day(creation_date) AS lst_day_mon from default.test_hudi_rds_4""").show()
```

**fncl_qtr_key** can also be done similar to this. You could optimize this query as you use.

Here is the output of the above query:[image]

Please let me know if it helps you.